# run fetched script only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following code:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="$.getScript('http://www.example.com/x.js')">aaa</a>
```

i want to only run `x.js` one time, what in `jQuery` can i use to make it execute `x.js` only one time?

thanks.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to attach your event handler through [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) instead:

HTML:

```
<a id="example" href="#">aaa</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#example").one("mouseover", function() {
  $.getScript('http://www.example.com/x.js');
});
```

Alternatively, if you have to use the inline scripts, you could set a flag and only call `$.getScript()` the first time (this is not recommended):

HTML:

```
<a id="example" href="#" onmouseover="doMouseOver();">aaa</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var scriptRan = false;
function doMouseOver() {
  if (!scriptRan) {
    scriptRan = true;
    $.getScript('http://www.example.com/x.js');
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that, i want code that i can put into the onmouseover attribute.

Comment: @noz70629 You should be avoiding inline scripts and styles whenever possible.

Comment: @noz70629 I gave you an alternative if for some reason you absolutely need to use the inline script